# Performing a query on the lowest level of a tree-structured Dojo store

Tags: store, dojo

Let's say we have a nested data structure like so:

```
[
   {  
     "name": "fruits",
     "items": [
        { "name": "apple" ...}
        { "name": "lemon" ...}
        { "name": "peach" ...}
     ]
   }
   {
     "name": "veggies", 
     "items": [
        { "name": "carrot" ...}
        { "name": "cabbage" ...}
     ]
   } 
   { 
     "name": "meat",
     "items": [
       { "name": "steak" ...}
       { "name": "pork" ...}
     ]
   }
]
```

The above data is placed in a dojo/store/Memory. I want to perform a query for items that contain the letter "c", but only on the lower level (don't want to query the categories).

With a generic dojo/store/Memory, it's query function only applies a filter on the top level, so the code

```
store.query(function(item) {
    return item.name.indexOf("c") != -1;
});
```

will only perform the query on the category names (fruits,  veggies, etc) instead of the actual items.

Is there a straight-forward way to perform this query on the child nodes, and if there's a match, return all children as well as the parent? For instance, the "c" query would return the "fruits" node with it's "peach" child only, "veggies" would remain intact, and "meat" would be left out of the query results entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course define your own checking method in the store's query method. I don't check if this code runs perfectly, but I guess you could pretty much get what it's meant to do.

```
store.query(function(item) {
    var found = {
        name: "",
        items: []
    };
    var children = item.items;
    d_array.forEach(children, function(child) {
        if (child.name.indexOf("c") != -1) {
            found.name = item.name;
            found.items.push(child); 
        }
    });
    return found;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, printemps. The code you provided will simply cause the query to return the top-level data and all its children if any single one of the children matches the query value ("c").

I can rework the code to place all matches in a temporary array and replicate the store's structure, but I had hoped to have the store query return the necessary structure without doing any work outside of the query function. Is this possible?